# yocto adding packages /packages-groups in custom distro

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, busybox

i am facing problem in adding packages/package-groups to custom distro file which is based on poky distro.

i have created custom distro file and enabled it in local.oonf file. it is compiling perfectly, But when add any package or package-group to distro file using variables like :

POKY_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES , DISTRO_FEATURES and POKY_DEFAULT_EXTRA_RDEPENDS then these packages are neither compiled or become part of final image.

Content of my custom distro file :

```
include conf/distro/poky.conf
DISTRO = "paras"
DISTRO_NAME = "Paras-Linux"
DISTRO_VERSION = "1.0"
DISTRO_CODENAME = "orange"


PARAS_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES = "\
packagegroup-paras-core \
packagegroup-paras-compress \
packagegroup-paras-network \
"

POKY_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES = "largefile multiarch ${PARAS_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES}"

PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_rpm"


PREFERRED_PROVIDER_base-utils = "packagegroup-paras-core"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils = "packagegroup-paras-core"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-hwclock = "util-linux-hwclock"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-syslog = "syslog-ng"

INIT_MANAGER ?= "systemd"
```

i have also tried using distro_feature variable :

```
DISTRO_FEATURES ?= "${DISTRO_FEATURES_DEFAULT} ${POKY_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES} ${PARAS_DEFAULT_DISTRO_FEATURES}"
```

is it possible to add package/package-groups in distro file if not then what is the point of distro file ?

Note : i am using yocto [branch hardknott]

Answer (score 0):

You can add

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " package_name" to your conf/local.conf file in your build folder

Make sure that you leave a space in the quotes - that is intentional as this is a concatenated string of package names.

Comment: If the package is custom to the distro, then it should be configured in the distro and not local.conf